# How is temporal frequency multiplied by spatial wavelength equivalent to velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

My book seems to be implying that the temporal frequency when multiplied by the spatial wavelength gives the velocity of the wave. I cannot see how this is true. Can someone explain?

Here are screenshots of the problem 1.1b:

Since n = c/v, it is implying that $n = c/(f*\lambda)$ but f is obviously temporal frequency and the lambda without any subscript is the spatial wavelength.

Source: http://optics.sgu.ru/~ulianov/Students/Books/Applied_Optics/Keigo%20Iizuka%20Elements%20of%20Photonics.%20Vol%201.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Periodic Wave formula; need explanation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88817)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, the wavelength $\lambda$ is the distance between consecutive peaks or troughs of a waveform, or in other words, the spatial length of a full cycle of the wave.  The frequency $f$ is the number of wave cycles passing a fixed point in space in some fixed amount of time.  The inverse of frequency is the period, $T=\frac{1}{f}$ of the wave.  That is, the time it takes for a full cycle of the wave to pass our predefined point (note the units: $\left(\frac{\text{cycles}}{\text{s}}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\text{s}}{\text{cycle}}$).  From this, we can see that the speed of the wave (more accurately, its phase speed), is just the distance between peaks/troughs (i.e. the spatial length of one cycle of the wave) divided by the time it takes for one cycle to pass by our fixed point, since a wave moving at this speed will have traveled one wavelength in one period:
  $$v=\frac{\lambda}{T}$$

But from the definition of a period, we see that this is equivalent to 
$$v=\lambda f$$

Comment: @Goldname please let me know if there's anything I can add to my answer to help you understand, and consider accepting one of the given answers if you find it sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the wave equation is $E = E_0 e^{i(\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r-\omega t)}$ where $k= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and $\omega = 2 \pi f$.

When you want to measure the speed of a wave you could measure the distance travelled by a crest in unit time, or the distance travelled by a trough in unit time etc.
What in fact you are doing is observing the passage of the wave where the value of $E$ is constant.
So if it is a crest you are observing the passage of the part of the wave where $E=E_0$ and when observing a trough you are observing the passage of the part of the wave where $E=-E_0$.

In fact what you are doing is following a part of the wave travelling in the $\hat r$ direction such that $\mathbf k\cdot \mathbf r-\omega t = kr-\omega t = \rm constant$.

If you differentiate this expression with respect to time you get that $k\frac{dr}{dt} - \omega =0 \Rightarrow \frac{dr}{dt} = v = \frac {\omega}{k} = f \lambda$ where $v$ is the speed of a crest, trough etc and is the speed of the wave.